# Linq - Join where ID's !=, select new + distinct?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes.

Course;

```
 public class Course
{
    //pk
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public int SourceCourseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Registration

```
public class Registration
{
    //primary key
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...more fields
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to obtain a collection of annonymous objects with the two fields below  for all Courses that are Distinct in the registrations table that are not in the Courses table.

```
var distinctCourses = (from registration in db.Registrations
                       join courses in db.Courses on registration.CourseId equals courses.SourceCourseId
                       where registration.CourseId != courses.SourceCourseId
                       select new
                            {
                                SourceCourseId = registration.CourseId,
                                Name = registration.CourseName,

                            }).Distinct().ToList();
```

For some reason the above is returning 0...  Any suggestions?

Comment: You are joining (a left join in SQL terms) which restricts you to registrations which are in the courses table.

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars I think he is doing a full join.... what he needs if I read the question correctly is a left join.  i.e.  "in the registrations table that are not in the Courses"

Comment: Yes I have registration data.  I need to query the registration data to pull out distinct course data.  The first pass through is easy;  Get all course data in the registration data that is distinct, save to courses.  Every check thereafter is what I'm after which is;  Get all course data in registration data that is distinct and that is not already in the courses table, get.

Comment: plz confirm you are intending to join on courses.SourceCourseID.  Since Id is pk for that table the more usual (but not necessarily correct) join would be on ID:   join courses in db.Courses on registration.CourseId equals courses.Id

Comment: Id in Courses is not derived from the Registration.CourseId, its an auto generated PK.  I'm assigning the Registration.CourseId to an int property in Course called SourceCourseId.  Don't ask, long story.

Comment: @Sam, yes sorry, that's what I was thinking but wrote the wrong thing. Doh. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try a left join:

```
var query = from r in registrations
join c in courses on r.CourseId equals c.id into newCourses
from nullCourse in newCourses.DefaultIfEmpty()
where nullCourse == null
select new { }
```

Edit - per comment from Alex :
Also, your where clause needs to change to

```
where nullCourse == null
```

Edit - changed join columns and added correct where clause.

Edit - group registrations on CourseID so they will be distinct

```
var distinctCourses = 
    (from registration in db.Registrations 
     group registration by registration.CourseId into grp
     from reg in grp
     join courses in db.Courses on reg.CourseId equals courses.SourceCourseId into newCourses
     from nullCourse in newCourses.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where nullCourse == null
     select new
     {
        SourceCourseId = reg.CourseId,
        Name = reg.CourseName,

     }).ToList();
```

Comment: selecting nullCourse.Properties?

Comment: No  - nullCourse will be null.  I understand your question to mean you registrations where couse does not exist.  Your select statement looks fine.

Comment: I updated the query to group first so you should get distinct rows.

Comment: Is grouping faster than calling Distinct() before ToList()?

Comment: @JReam IDK you will have to test.  Please let me know your results thx.

Comment: I think .... calling Distinct() after the Select and before the .ToList() might be looking at all the selected values for a distinct combo?  Therefore if you have two course names that are the same with the same id's, but another field (not listed, lets say SubCourseName) is different, it will list the course twice.  If this is true (hoping someone can confirm) .... then group is a better route to get a distinct set of Courses regardless of its other properties.

Comment: Yes your assessment is correct - distinct looks at all values.  However there is one other thing you need to look at.  I believe distinct as you are using it operates on the result of your query.  So you are not "distincting" registrations or courses as you might expect.... you are distincting the new objects you create as a result of your select.  I believe group by gives you the result you want.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the explanation!  In the act of redoing the query following your logic, I'm able to ascertain the grp result via 'select grp).ToList()'.  However, I'm unable to query grp as you do above.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90355/discussion-between-jream-and-sam).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var result = Registrations.GroupJoin(Courses,r=>r.CourseId,c=>c.SourceCourseId,
                            (k,g) => new {k,g})
                            .Where(x=>x.g.Count()==0)
                            .Select(s=> new {id=s.k.CourseId,name=s.k.CourseName});
```

Comment: Appreciate this but  WAY over my head of understanding at the moment.  I'm new to LINQ, so I'm still taking baby steps.

Comment: What is RegistrationList?